# Solr Merge results

Tags: search, solr, merge, distributed

I use Solr for product filtering on our website,

for example you can have a product filter where you can filter database of Televisions by size, price, company etc.,. I found Solr+FilterQuery to be very efficeint for such functionality. I have a separate core that has the product info of all TVs in our DB.

I have another Core for product reviews. The review can be on a specific product type or company. So someone can write a review on a Samsung TV or Samsung customer service. So when someone searches for a text (for example "Samsung TV review" or "Samsung customer service"), I search this core.

Now I want to merge the results from the above cores. So when someone searches for 'samsung 46 lcd contrast ratio review', I esentially want to filter the TVs by Company (Samsung), then by size (46") and then find reviews that have text "contrast ratio review". I have no clue how to do this. Basically I want to merge the results by document ID and add additional colums for result 2 into result 1.

I have seen suggestions to flatten out the data but I want to use reviews index on a lot of other filters. So I am not sure if thats a good idea. Moreover if new reviews start coming in I dont want to reindex all the cores of products (even delta reindexing will touch lot of products).

Any ideas on how to acheieve this?

Comment: How do you plan to route the queries to the right cores? For ex. how do you know which queries should look up "reviews" core?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right what you are looking for is JOIN functionality.

http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/grouping-and-joining-in-lucenesolr

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join